# java : cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java

I was compiling an JAVA ( 1.4 varsion )file and was getting the following error
(about 100 times all are same).

```
Appli.java:721: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class License
location: class test.App.Appli
            License  sellLicense = sell.getLicense();
```

I used

```
   run/cmd/cd D:...../javac Appli.java
```

I had set the CLASSPATH variable, to the Classes folder of the java files I am presently running.

```
  Control panel/Settings/System/System Properties /Advanced/Environmental Variables/System Variables/ Add/CLASSPATH
```

Should I use

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Could we please see a sample of the code causing the errors?

Comment: Well, not all 721 lines of it, but a sample.

Comment: @vas: so you are putting the classes in a separate subtree, yes?  In that case, you probably forgot to "cd" to the right place before compiling and didn't set `-sourcepath`.  You need to do one or the other; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you need to compile the class License with the class Appli.  Take a look at the [Javac Documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html) for more details, but you can do something like the following:

```
javac Appli.java License.java
```

If License is in a library, you will need to add the library to your compilation classpath.  This is done with the -classpath flag:

```
javac -classpath "classpath" Appli.java
```

Comment: Should I use   javac -classpath "classpath" Appli.java
every time i execute "javac Appli.java"

Comment: @vas: yes ... or set $CLASSPATH, or use a build tool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the CLASSPATH and make sure that you are in the correct directory.

Assuming that `test.App.Appl` is trying to reference `test.App.License`, the directory structure should be:

```
/somedir/test
/somedir/test/App
/somedir/test/App/Appl.java
/somedir/test/App/License.java
```

You should set `$CLASSPATH` to `"/somedir"`, then change your current directory to `/somedir` and run the compiler as `javac test/App/*.java`; e.g.

```
$ export CLASSPATH="/somedir"
$ cd /somedir
$ javac test/App/*.java
```

You can also use the `-cp` command line option with the `javac` (and later the `java`) command, and you run the `javac` compiler from a different directory by using the `-sourcepath` option.

The other possibility is that the package for `License` is not `test.App`.  If that is the case, you need to adjust the directory structure to match the package naming, and add an `import` statement to the `Appl` class.

EDIT:  If you notice a `build.xml` or `pom.xml` (or possibly even a `Makefile`) in the source tree, you probably should not be using `javac` directly.  A `build.xml` is for building using `Ant`, a 'pom.xml`is for Maven (or Ivy) and a`Makefile`or`makefile`is for`make`.

Comment: Setting the classpath environment variable is so last millenium... It's best not to set it at all, the current directory will be searched in any case.

Comment: @Michael: actually, he should really be using Ant or Maven, so lets not split hairs.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing an `import` statement.

Comment: I am trying to run an pre-existing code being used for production